# TinyMCE - Insert combobox and selected value with formatting

Tags: javascript, formatting, tinymce

I'm trying to figure out TinyMCE. And I've looked at the examples, but it seems the examples use different ways of achieving the tasks. And I'm having a hard time putting it together to get what I need.

Basically, I need two comboboxes with a set of values. And a third button to insert the selected value from both the first comboboxes. And I want to insert these with a specific CSS class for formatting, if possible (I reckon in is).

Here's the code I've got so far. I'd really appreciate some help in this!

```
// Creates a new plugin class and a custom listbox
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin', {
    createControl: function(n, cm) {
        switch (n) {
            case 'comboboxChordsPrimary':
                var mlb = cm.createListBox('comboboxChordsPrimary', {
                     title : 'Akkorder',
                     onselect : function(v) {
                         tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Value selected:' + v);
                     }
                });

                // Add some values to the list box
                mlb.add('C', 'C');
                mlb.add('C#-Db', 'C#-Db');
                mlb.add('D', 'D');
                mlb.add('D# -Eb', 'D# -Eb');
                mlb.add('E', 'E');
                mlb.add('F', 'F');
                mlb.add('F# -Gb', 'F# -Gb');
                mlb.add('G# -Ab', 'G# -Ab');
                mlb.add('A', 'A');
                mlb.add('A# -Bb', 'A# -Bb');
                mlb.add('B', 'B');

                // Return the new listbox instance
                return mlb;

        case 'comboboxChordsSecondary':
                var mlb2 = cm.createListBox('comboboxChordsSecondary', {
                     title : 'Akkorder',
                     onselect : function(v) {
                         tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Value selected:' + v);
                     }
                });

                // Add some values to the list box
                mlb2.add(' ', ' ');
                mlb2.add('m', 'm');
                mlb2.add('dim', 'dim');
                mlb2.add('aug', 'aug');
                mlb2.add('7', '7');
                mlb2.add('m7', 'm7');
                mlb2.add('maj7', 'maj7');

                // Return the new listbox instance
                return mlb2;

        case 'btnAddChord':
                var mlb3 = cm.createButton('btnAddChord', {
                     title : 'Add',
                     onselect : function(v) {
            cm.focus();
            cm.selection.setContent(comboboxChordsPrimary.value + comboboxChordsSecondary.value);
                     }
                });

                // Return the new listbox instance
                return mlb3;

        }   

        return null;
    }
});

// Register plugin with a short name
tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin);

// Initialize TinyMCE with the new plugin and listbox
tinyMCE.init({
    plugins : '-example', // - tells TinyMCE to skip the loading of the plugin
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "comboboxChordsPrimary,comboboxChordsSecondary,btnAddChord,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"    
});
```

I'm not even sure if I approached this task the correct way. I've done this exact this before in VB.NET, but Javascript really confuses me. It's because of those damn brackets :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a tinymce button which will read the selected values.
Here is a working tinymce fiddle which should point you into the correct direction: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gJcaab

If you encounter any problems - let me know.

Comment: Hi it no longer seems to work. What version of tinymce were you targeting? I was looking for an example of 
tinymce.ui.ListBox in API version 4.

Comment: tinymce3 (have a look a the answer date - in 2011 there was tinymce3 only) which much likely is the reason that it does not work for you

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wonder how hard it is to get it working in tinymce4?